# Angularitics2 not triggering route changes in Google Tag Manager/Analytics

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

Hi I have setup Google Tag Manager and added the script at the beginning of the body tag.
I have set it up like it shows in the readme and added the AngulariticsModule, Angularitics2GoogleTagManager etc. In the readme it says that adding this it will automatically send route changes to Analytics in my case Analytics inside Google Tag Manager.

But when I go to Google Analytics and view Realtime Overview.
I can see that it shows up correctly but when I go to a different route it doesn't update the activepage.
So I am not sure if it works correctly. However when I press F5 it does change the activepage inside Analytics.

I have a feeling Angularitics is not working in my angular2 app. Just the script inside the index.

I am using Angular Cli 1.0 which uses Angular v4.0.

Index.html

```
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<app-root></app-root>
```

App.Module

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleTagManager ]),
],
```

Router

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/nl/landing', pathMatch: 'full', //main language set here
},
{
    path: ':lang',
    resolve: {root: RootResolver},

    children: [

        {
            path: 'landing',
            component: LandingComponent,
            data: {title: 'Landing'}
        },
        {
            path: 'earlybird',
            component: EarlybirdComponent,
        },
    ]
}
```

AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(
        private title: Title,
        private meta: Meta,
        public angulartics2GoogleTagManager: Angulartics2GoogleTagManager,
)
```

What do I have to do more to make it work?
Am I missing something? Or do I have to setup something inside GTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's still looking for something similar,

If all you want to is to track all page urls in a Single Page Application, the autotrack library solves the problem: https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack

I did this implementation directly in my application without using the Angularitics or autotrack library as I had a project that needed more customization for tracking.

So I wanted to do something like -

In the routes definition file:

```
{ path: 'product/:id', loadChildren: './...', data: { pageView: '/product/[:id]' } },
```

where a page view event is sent only if I define `data: { pageView: ... }`

and `pageView` is the page url is the url data I want to send in the event. `[:param]` is a regex that I set myself to send params.

Define a GTM class somewhere e.g. `gtm.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

declare let dataLayer: any;

@Injectable()
export class GTM {
    constructor() {
        // The dataLayer needs to be initialized
        if (typeof dataLayer !== 'undefined' && dataLayer) {
            dataLayer = (<any> window).dataLayer = (<any> window).dataLayer || [];
        }
    }

    // Send virtualPageviews via  dataLayer.push
    // Change this dataLayer event as you see fit
    pageTrack(path: string) {
        // However you wish to send event
        dataLayer.push({
            event: 'virtualPageview',
            url: path
        });
    }

    /**
     * Gets the full page view with substituted params
     * e.g. converts '/product/[:id]' to
     * '/product/12345' using resolved ActivatedRoute params
     * @param  {ActivatedRoute} route    [description]
     * @param  {string}         pageView [description]
     * @return {string}                  pageView path with resolved params
     */
    getResolvedPageView(route: ActivatedRoute, pageView: string) {
        // Check if a param is referenced like this e.g. /product/[:id]
        let regExp = new RegExp(/(\[:)(\w+)(\])/g);
        if (regExp.test(pageView)) {
            // Params object
            let params = route.firstChild.snapshot.params;
            pageView = pageView.replace(regExp, (match, p1, p2, p3) => {
                // p1 = [:
                // p2 = reference / param / whateverWord
                // p3 = ]
                return params[p2];
            });
        }
        return pageView;
    }
}
```

Then hook it to the route navigation end event, I did this in AppComponent:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { GTM } from './gtm-file-location';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private gtm: GTM,
        ...
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // GTM Analytics pageView tracking
        // Use 'pageView' param in data object attached to route
        // Nice article on how this is done:
        // https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events
        this.router.events
            .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
            .map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; };
                return route;
            })
            .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap((route) => route.data) // Get route data object
            .subscribe((event) => {
                // Only send pageView event if data: { pageView: 'xxx' } is set
                // Or remove if condition to send everything
                if (event['pageView']) {
                    let trackedUrl = this.gtm.getResolvedPageView(this.activatedRoute, event['pageView']);
                    this.gtm.pageTrack(trackedUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ...
```

There might be better ways. Hopefully this is helpful to someone!